# Hive query selecting top 2 rows by percentage count and display as columns

Tags: hive

I have a table something like below in my hadoop cluster

```
ID  |   CATEGORY     |  COUNT
101 |   A            |   40
101 |   B            |   40
101 |   C            |   20
102 |   D            |   10
102 |   A            |   20
102 |   E            |   30
102 |   F            |   40
```

I have to write a Hive query which will show IDs and top 2 categories by percentage count as columns. So my result table should look like

```
ID  |   CAT1 |  %   | CAT2  | %
101 |   A    |   40 | B     | 40
102 |   F    |   40 | E     | 30
```

Please keep in my mind that this is only a sample table which I have kept very simple for explaining purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the top 2 per ID, you can use the `rank()` function, see example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/taylor22/entry/hive_0_11_may_15).

To get percentage out of overall, you can join on ID with an aggregate table:

`select ID,sum(count) as sum from input_table group by ID`

And finally, if you want to turn the table from `ID, Cat, %`  to one ID per row, you would need to use `collect_list` for `Cat` and `%` in a sub query and then create a column for the array elements

```
Select ID, categories[0], pcts[0],categories[1], pcts[1] from (
  Select a.ID, collect_list(Cat) as categories , collect_list(Count/sum) as pcts from (
    Select ID, Cat, Count, rank from (
      SELECT ID, Cat, Count, 
      rank() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Count DESC) as rank
      FROM input_table) inner where rank <= 2 ) a, 
    (select ID,sum(count) as sum from input_table group by ID) b where a.ID = b.ID
  group by a.ID ) inner;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I substituted my variables in the query and added the group by ID in the sum(Count) sub-query as it was giving an error but now I get "Invalid table alias or column reference 'rank'". I changed the word rank to something else but still get an error. Any idea what might be going on? thanks

Comment: Apparently rank can't be referenced there... another sub-query is needed. I edited the answer

Comment: Works great. Thanks Alex!